# function pointers in loops

Tags: c, optimization

for my bachelor thesis I have written a program (in C) to sort large tables and now everything works as it should. For some of my test files, however, the program is a little slow. To be able to store temporary data more efficently, the user may specify a data type for each column of the table. Then the input data is first parsed into some binary format, then sorted and finally transformed back into its textual form.

For each data type one has to implement four functions (encode, decode, getlength and compare) and pointers to these are stored in an array for each column. So, to do anything with a row of the table, I have to call the correct function for each row in a loop, which has a fair overhead if the columns are rather short.

As an example, here is the code of my row compare function (called from qsort):

```
int line_cmp(const void *p1,const void *p2)
{
    int i,o1=0,o2=0,r;

    for(i=0;i<opt.nocols;i++)
        if((r=(*opt.cols[i].cmp)(*(char* const*)p1,&o1,
                                 *(char* const*)p2,&o2)))
            return r;

    return 0;
}
```

This function loops through all columns and if the called function returns a value other than 0 (meaning not equal) the value is returned (just like qsort demands).

Now my question is, how can this (or similar) function be optimized (if possible at all), especially when all the pointers are only setup once and then never changed during the whole program?

EDIT: I use function pointers so that it is possible for a third person to develop arbitrary data types. These would then be loaded through (dlopen, etc.). Thus, I can not think of a common binary format to compare columns and the binary data is just a black box for my program.

Comment: The code you've presented is basically a bare-bones loop with a single call each time through. It's hard to see how that can be optimized further. I guess you didn't post where the encode, decode, and getlength functions are used?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: I chose this function as an example, because it is the longest. The other functions are just a for and a call to the function.

Comment: Why are you not using profiling tools in order to find out where the bottleneck lies.

Comment: @milan: well, I did. The bottleneck is there. The above function is the workhorse of my program and thus I want to optimize it.

Comment: When you say "one" has to implement four functions, do you mean you or the user?  In other words, do you have a limited set of data types, or the user can create any arbitrary type?  Is it feasible to make a common binary format that can be compared with the same algorithm?

Comment: The profiling may indicate you need to change sorting algorithms.  If your sort is O(n^2), you'll get more impact from optimizing the sort to O(n log n) than this.

Comment: @Karl Bielefeldt: Thanks. See edit.

Comment: @B Mitch: The sorting algorithm used is quicksort. I believe the qsort() function is optimized to death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the assembler that your code produces, but you might have a problem of too many indirections, here, and also that the compiler has to reload the contents of `opt`.

Also depends a little bit on how your global `opt` is defined (`const` or not) how much the compiler is able to optimize. Since you have function calls between the iterative usage of `opt` the compiler wouldn't know if the value has changed.

Try to do something like

```
size_t nocols = opt.nocols
columnType const*const myFunc = opt.cols;
```

and use `nocols` and `myFunc[i].comp` for the loop.

Comment: Tried it and it was slower by 10% and 3%, which could be due to measuring tolerances (made only 5 tests each). The assembler code of the loop, however, was shorter, which leads me to believe that your way is better if there are lots of columns (tested files had 3 and 30 columns). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see room for much optimization within the function you've posted. It is simply a `for` loop that calls a function each time through.

Calling a function pointer is efficient. Even if you had a common binary format that could be used to compare all item types, I doubt that would be much faster than calling a compare function specific for the current type.

One possible idea is to have your user-defined function compare all columns. That could eliminate the `for` loop in the function you posted. Although a similar loop may be required in the specialized function, reducing a number of calls may shave a little time. However, if a single row can have multiple types, that wouldn't work.

Beyond that, I suspect any further optimizations that could be made would be part of your code not posted here. I don't have enough information to know what, if any, could be made there.

Comment: Moving the for loop into the type specific function will mak things worse, because the comparison moves from left to right and stops when two columns are found to be unequal. If you move the for loop a level down, I can end up comparing columns 1,3,4,... when the data in column 2 is of another type and not equal.  I don't see any room for improvement, too, but then again 1 million eyes see more than two. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make it Concurrent, upgrade your design to a Lock-Free Concurrent Sort. Maybe lock-free is more of a master leve project, if you can't think of a Lock-Free, go for a lock-based one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the sort is already concurrent (in a higher level, though). So the program already uses all available processing power. Forgot to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to switch to C++?

I'm asking because the C++ STL's template sort algorithm usually leads to an inlined comparison and a nice performance boost. The difference ist most pronounced when comparing simple types like `int`.

If you have to stay with C you could try to get your hands at quicksort source code and  embed a direct call of the comparison. This will manually achieve what STL and templates automatically do for you.

Having read your EDIT, I think you cannot really speed up the sort without some radical change like parallel sorting or requiring the user to supply the data in a better suited format.

One more idea: Perhaps you can speed up the sort by sorting successively according to the single columns. This could profit a fair amount from cache locality.

Comment: No, i can't switch to C++. That would mean rewriting 4500 lines of code. I already tried a modified version of qsort (with inlined calls) but I could not measure any effect.

Comment: As you are already profiling I assume you are already using compiler optimization, yes?